# Parsing JSON values and feeding them in a loop

Tags: python, json, loops

I have the following JSON code:

```
"configuration": {
    "contents": [
      {
        "file": "path/page.xhtml",
        "index": 1,
      },
      {
        "file": "path/p-001.xhtml",
        "index": 2,
      },
      {
        "file": "path/p-002.xhtml",
        "index": 3,
      },
      {
        "file": "path/p-003.xhtml",
        "index": 4,
      }
    ]
}
```

In Python, I wish to feed all the "file" values into an URL in a loop one by one, how should I do so?

Current code: (metadata containing the JSON data)

```py
metaconfiguration = metadata['configuration']
metacontents = metaconfiguration['contents']
path = metacontents[s]['file']

Count = 1
while Count < 5:
    url = "https://example.com/"+path
    Count += 1
```

Note that I will soon replace the "Count" value with the length of "contents" after I will be done with this problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to loop over `metacontents` to find the path elements:

```py
import json

txt = '''{"configuration": {
    "contents": [
      {
        "file": "path/page.xhtml",
        "index": 1
      },
      {
        "file": "path/p-001.xhtml",
        "index": 2
      },
      {
        "file": "path/p-002.xhtml",
        "index": 3
      },
      {
        "file": "path/p-003.xhtml",
        "index": 4
      }
    ]
}}'''

metadata = json.loads(txt)

metaconfiguration = metadata['configuration']
metacontents = metaconfiguration['contents']
for d in metacontents:
    url = 'https://example.com/' + d['file']
    print(url)
```

Output:

```
https://example.com/path/page.xhtml
https://example.com/path/p-001.xhtml
https://example.com/path/p-002.xhtml
https://example.com/path/p-003.xhtml
```